# How to Find Unique Rows without GroupBy, Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have a SQL field that I only want to appear in a field in my sql query results depending on the value of `FamilyType`.

So when the Family Type is `3B` then I want `FamilyID` to appear.

I do not want to have duplicate rows (without using `distinct` or `group by` or `where clause = 3B`).

These are my fields in table: `Family`.

Fields:
`MemberID, FamilyID, FamilyType`.

So there are 2 rows in the order of fields above:

1. 3400, 233,  3B
2. 3400, null, ZH

```
    select MemberID,  
     CASE WHEN FamilyType = '3B' THEN FamilyID 
     ELSE '' END AS FamilyIDFinal
    from Family
```

This still produces 2 rows. I would like:

1. 3400, 233

instead of:

1. 3400, 233
2. 3400, null

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: "without using distinct or groupby or where clause = '3B'" -- in other words without really using SQL... Why do you have such restrictions?

Comment: Why not simply `select MemberID, FamilyType from Family where FamilyType = '3B'`?

Comment: This makes no sense. If you want to exclude rows from a select statement you use a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in theory you can:

```
select top (1) with ties
  MemberID,
  CASE WHEN FamilyType = '3B' THEN FamilyID ELSE 0 END AS FamilyIDFinal
from Family
order by row_number() over(partition by MemberID order by case FamilyType when '3B' then 1 else 2 end);
```

However, making this query efficient will be quite difficult. An index like `(MemberID, FamilyType) include (FamilyID)` should work, but it will be tightly coupled with the logic of this single query. From personal experience, `top (1) with ties` is usually a solution of the last resort, when everything else fails to deliver. Usually it's better to revise the data model.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was using a With SQL Clause with a subquery - and the  basic code example I listed above to pull out only specific rows without duplication. Thank you.